# Is it right to use PAST SIMPLE instead of PRESENT PERFECT here?

Tags: usage, passive-voice

I know that using the present perfect in the main clause  after since-clause is widely used as in Example 1. But is it right to use the past simple as in Example 2?

1. Since 1922, Mount Everest has been climbed by more than 400 people.
2. Since 1922, Mount Everest was climbed by more  than 400 people.

By the way, there is no context at all.

Comment: since,has been is better. You can use what you like or you can choose to sound more educated as opposed to less educated. This is not dialectal. It is about level of education.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have been learning tenses as well and I am proud to say that I am absolutely certain that the present perfect is the right choice, because from 1922 up until 2018 covers almost 100 years, from the past to the present. The past simple would be the right choice if you talk about the past, for example: in 1922 5 people climbed the Mount Everest. In speech people often use the wrong tenses, I suppose this happens in any language, informal use differs from formal use, slang for example.